# CloudFlare - кеширование, проблемы

Tags: веб-программирование

Есть сайт, портал, с файлами (изображения и т.д), часто случается так что уже добавленные материалы приходиться модерировать, изменять изображения которые уже кешировал CloudFlare, и после обновления на сайте, приходиться еще и в ручную вбивать в CloudFlare URL обновленного файла, что бы он его перекешировал. Как вообще быть? Писать функции которые будут отправлять API запросы, или это как-то можно настроить. Та же самая беда и с аватарами...

Comment: насколько помню достаточно параметр антикэша передавать, т.е. обновили картинку - обновили антикэш, тогда cdn приходится лезть на сервер за свежей картинкой

Comment: а как это сделать? или где почитать?

Comment: антикэш - имеется ввиду что-то типа *http://your/link/image.png?123*, т.е. обновили картинку - заменили 123 на 124 (или любое другое)